# Newsletter subscribe not working on homepage [custom theme]

Tags: magento2, newsletter

I copy this template from

> vendor/magento/module-newsletter/view/frontend/templates/subscribe.phtml

There's no js console error and any other error on server log. Subscribe is not working (email id not saved on admin panel). how to tackle it.it doesn't show any message alert.

my newsletter template  in

> mynamespace/mytheme/Magento_Newsletter/templates/
>   **newsletter-footer.phtml**

```
<section class="signup-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="signup-container clearfix">
            <article>  <span>
                <h3>Sign Up For Newsletter</h3>
                <p>Be the First to Know. Sign up to newsletter today</p>
                </span> </article>
            <article>
                <form class="form subscribe"
                      novalidate
                      action="<?php echo $block->getFormActionUrl() ?>"
                      method="post"
                      data-mage-init='{"validation": {"errorClass": "mage-error"}}'
                      id="newsletter-validate-detail">

                            <input name="email" placeholder="<?php echo __('Enter you email address here...'); ?>" type="email" id="newsletter"
                                   data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
                            <button class="action subscribe primary" type="submit">

                            </button>

                </form>
            </article>
        </div>
        <!--end of div signup-container-->
    </div>
    <!--end of div container-->
</section>
```

**cms_index_index.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="main">
        <referenceContainer name="container.global" htmlClass="someotherclass"  >
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="newsletter" template="Magento_Newsletter::newsletter-footer.phtml"/>

        </referenceContainer>
    </referenceContainer>
```

**showing on homepage and validate email also**
[image]

[image]

Comment: The folder name should be "Magento_Newsletter" instead of "Magento-Newsletter".

Comment: @kunj spell mistake

Comment: This template is calling on frontend or not? Because you have changed the template name. Did you call the new template name from xml? If yes then please post the xml code on your question.

Comment: Can you update the xml code?

Comment: @SukumarGorai updated question !

Comment: Wait I am posting my answer

Comment: Check the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below xml code instead of yours:

```
<referenceContainer name="main">
    <referenceContainer name="container.global" htmlClass="someotherclass"  >
        <block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="newsletter" template="Magento_Newsletter::newsletter-footer.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Happy to Help!.

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, I need your help?

Comment: Post your question please.

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, I have 2 years experience in Magento e-commerce website. But  I don't have knowledge on extension development. So, I want to learn magento2 coding. Please suggest me any tutorials.

Comment: Hi @ Sukumar Gorai, Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the right path for you override and place the template in

> mynamespace/mytheme/Magento_Newsletter/templates

You can also check your code again and compare it with the original code in the vendor package.

Comment: I compare code . Is any other file I need to include ??